# JSON Lint throwing parsing error

Tags: json, jsonlint

JSON Lint throwing parsing error for following string. I am saying it as string because, i got this data in string format and then I generate this code. Isn't it a valid JSON? Please help

```
 [
        ​{
            "x": "57",
            "y": "30",
            "z": "20",
            "name": "xyz"
        },
        {
            "x": "0",
            "y": "0",
            "z": "20",
            "name": "ss"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Well done using copy-and-paste to put the JSON in your question rather than retyping. If you'd retyped it (as people do, I don't know why) I couldn't have answered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be valid JSON if it didn't have an invisible character (a zero-width space) just prior to the first `{`. It's that character, [U+200B](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=200B), that the parser is choking on.

Comment: Oh, how to get rid of it?

Comment: @RajatAgarwal: Well, it shouldn't be there, it's a fault in whatever's generating the JSON. So the best thing is to fix whatever's generating the invalid JSON. As a second-best fallback, you could remove it from your string prior to parsing, e.g. `str = str.replace(/\u200B/g, "");` (that's JavaScript; I don't know what environment you're using for processing, but presumably it has a way to remove characters from strings). Of course, that would remove it from within strings in the JSON as well, where it could be valid.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using JavaScript only, and I want JSON so that I can feed it into Fusion Charts to display charts.

Comment: One of the best ways to check this, is at a site like https://kadebom.com/jsonlint.html or jsonlint.com